# Run Process From Different User, Without Password, but from Admin (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, passwords, impersonation

I need to monitor other accounts on a Windows Server, and have figured out that to do so, I have to be able to run a monitoring process on them. The main program runs from a full-access (possibly NT_AUTHORITY) account, but all ways of starting processes seem to require the user password! help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create this as a service instead and when installed supply password for the service properties (which user you want to run it as). Then the need to re-enter password should disappear.

Comment: unfortunately, this is on a server, and has to run on ALL accounts, and it is for school, so I doubt the students will give their password